# Using Git as a patching solution for generic software

Tags: c#, git, patch

I am the developer of a C# application which I ship to users. It is currently small enough that I simply download the newest build in it's entirety if one is available.
At some point I will need to make smarter patches. It randomly occurred to me that this is basically what Git and SVN do.

Are there any examples of someone using for e.g git pull on a client PC to update their software? I would need to ship git.exe probably and run it in silent mode. I believe this is how some enterprise do their updates, however I can't find much info on it.

If this works it would be much easier than implementing my own patching solution.

Comment: Git is meant for text and is very bad at handling binary files. Most git operations on binary files are either slow or don't work at all.

Comment: What about using Git LFS?

Comment: I'm doubtful that automating git will prove to be much easier than implementing your own. Also, older versions will remain in git even if your latest version is the only file in the latest branch, so your repository will grow and grow over time without careful maintenance.

Comment: Don't reinvent it for yourself, there are plenty of frameworks for autoupdating. Such as https://github.com/Tyrrrz/Onova

Answer (score 2):

Git is not a great tool for patching software, particularly on PCs, for many reasons.

First, a Git repository has the history of every revision, meaning as you release more versions, your download directory will increase in size with every release.  The users of your software won't appreciate this extra disk space usage.  Even if you do some unpleasant things to solve this, Git will still store some of those objects for a while.

Second, on Windows, having a functional Git implementation requires not only the Git binary, but a shell and full suite of POSIX tools, since Git relies on a POSIX environment.  This isn't really a problem on Unix, but on Windows, this is a potentially significant amount of additional software to ship.  In addition, you can't just automatically ship your own, because it might conflict with the version already installed.

Third, Git operates a little differently from other software on a typical PC.  You need to consider things like whether the system is using a proxy, or requires a custom certificate to handle a TLS MITM device, and if so, whether that's a configuration you think is work supporting (especially the latter, which, while required in some corporate environments, is a security problem).  Git has custom configuration for all of these things that doesn't necessarily work the same way as the system settings.

Fourth, you have to keep Git up to date as well.  Git, like any piece of nontrivial software, requires security updates.  While Git has a reasonably good security history, it uses other software, such as TLS libraries, which will need frequent updates.

Finally, Git reads data from a wide variety of places via its configuration files.  While it is possible to avoid reading from most of these locations, doing so is tricky and requires intimate knowledge of how it work, since you won't want to use any local Git configuration that the user has set up.

Ultimately, I would recommend using a well-known piece of software for performing automated updates.  If you can't find one, you could use a tool like `xdelta` to produce incremental binary patches you can apply.  Note that you will need to digitally sign security updates using robust algorithms to prevent tampering, and use secure versions of TLS to download those updates via HTTPS.  Failing to do either of those would be considered a security vulnerability.

In general, this is a hard problem, which on Linux is generally solved by distributions.  I would not recommend rolling your own solution here.